# Specifying maven options when running maven lifecycle goals in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have an Intellij maven project and am able to use the View|Toolbars|Maven Projects , then select a specific maven module.  From there i click on some lifecycle components, e.g

```
clean compile package
```

and run them.  So far OK. But I need to add some maven options. What are my choices here?  Do i need to set a static MAVEN_OPTS environment variable?  The downside is it would be applied equally to ALL invocations of maven.

Is there any way to apply maven options e.g. -DskipTests to a single maven run as part of selecting the lifecycle targets on the GUI?

**UPDATE**

There is actually a nondescript icon for "Toggle skipTests mode"  on the maven toolbar.  However we have other settigs to include on the maven command line so that icon is insufficient.

Comment: You can create a run configuration for your maven goal (right click on your lifecycle goal and select `Create {goal}...` (or just edit run configurations and add a maven configuration manually). There you can specify your exact command line and/or add profiles.

Comment: @DarekKay  The right click menu option does not offer "Create goal. I am on 13.1.4.   However the comment about Run|configurations is precisely what I needed.  Pleaes make this an answer and I will accept. As part of it maybe try to explain how/where you see the Create {goal} from the right click context menu (given I do not have it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a Maven run configuration. There are two ways to do so:

1. `Run` - `Edit Configurations` - `+` - `Maven`, or
2. Right click on your goal in the Maven view and select `Create {goal}...` (see screenshot:)

[image: create maven run configuration]

In the opened `Run Configuration` dialog use the `Command line` field to specify any command including arguments like `-DskipTests`